# Lack of mailbox for a calendar group

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, calendar, groups, outlook

**What I have:**
I am using SharePoint online (Office 365).

After adding a group calendar as a web part on my page and clicking on link to the group I get the following information:

> :-(
>   Something went wrong
>   We couldn't find a mailbox for this recipient. Either they don't have a mailbox or don't have a license assigned.

**Additional information:**
When I search available apps in my Office 365 online Outlook is not there.
Article which I used as a reference:
https://sharepointmaven.com/a-review-of-all-the-calendar-options-in-sharepoint-and-office-365/
(Option 5)

**What I want to have:**
I want to create an Office 365 group calendar, be able to use it from Outlook (installed on desktop) and embed it in my modern page

Answer (score 1):

You could go to the Microsoft 365 admin center->Groups, check if the group have a mailbox. Make sure the group has a mailbox.

You could try to create a new Group, then add a group calendar web part in the page. See if it works.

[image]
[image]